# Выбор узла xml с помощью XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Необходимо найти Node в xml и достать в дальнейшем из него какую-то информацию. Решил использовать XPath.

Вот фрагмент xml. Необходимо найти и достать `message` с некоторым `id`.

```
<messages>
  <message id="afbaee5e-d537-44eb-abb1-365d9ffac99a">
    <author>slawiko</author>
    <text>Hello</text>
    <date>30-04-2015 15:57</date>
    <method>post</method>
  </message>
  <message id="e8ffe31a-0c4f-490c-aafc-fa9599339de2">
    <author>slawiko</author>
    <text>How are you?</text>
    <date>30-04-2015 15:57</date>
    <method>post</method>
  </message>
</messages>
```

Вот функция, в которой я пытаюсь это реализовать:

```
private static synchronized Node getNodeById(Document document, String id) 
        throws XPathExpressionException, IOException, SAXException,
               ParserConfigurationException {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//" + "message" + "[@id='" + id + "']";
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression);
    Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(document,  XPathConstants.NODE);
    return node;
}
```

Возвращённый этой функцией объект `Node` передается в функцию:

```
public static Message nodeToMessage(Node node) {
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    Element element = (Element)node;
    String id = element.getAttribute(ID);
    String author = null;
    String text = null;
    String date = null;
    int length = childNodes.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (AUTHOR.equals(childNodes.item(i).getNodeName())) {
            author = childNodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
        } else if (TEXT.equals(childNodes.item(i).getNodeName())) {
            text = childNodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
        } else if (DATE.equals(childNodes.item(i).getNodeName())) {
            date = childNodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
        }
    }
    Message message = new Message(id, author, text, date);
    return message;
}
```

Вероятно, этот Node достается неправильно. В дальнейшем, когда дебажу код, на строке с приведением типа, дебаг просто останавливается.

Помимо этого, функция `nodeToMessage` работает вовсе не так, как хотелось бы:
`childeNodes.getLength()` возвращает число 9, хотя видно, что должен вернуть 4. Из этого делают очередной вывод: что-то не так с Node.

Так вот вопрос: что здесь не так? И если здесь все так, то где может быть проблема?

Comment: Уточните какой пакет с xpath вы используете. Судя по всему javax.xml.xpath, однако есть определенные сомнения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отказался от этой идеи. Решил, что доставать Node мне не нужно. Стал просто менять внутри XML в нужном Node. В тот момент и понял, что неправильно понимал структуру XML документа. Уже со всеми правками, процесс замены выглядит так (работает корректно):

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(STORAGE_LOCATION);
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Node messageToUpdate = getNodeById(document, message.getId());

    if (messageToUpdate != null) {
        NodeList childNodes = messageToUpdate.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = childNodes.item(i);
            if (TEXT.equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                node.setTextContent(message.getText());
            }
        }
        Transformer transformer = getTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(STORAGE_LOCATION));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
```

Соответственно в функции getNodeById ничего не менял.